When would you take the derivative of a definite integral?

I understand how to take the derivative of a definite integral, but I'm curious as to when one would ever do this ?.
For example, in Integral Calculus we learn to execute expressions of the form
$$
\frac{\rm d}{{\rm d}x} \int_{\operatorname{f}\left(x\right)}^{\operatorname{g}\left(x\right)}\operatorname{h}\left(t\right) {\rm d}t\qquad
\mbox{( via the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus )}
$$ but I cannot for the life of me think of an instance where I've used this before.
I've definitely taken the derivative of an indefinite integral but not of a bounded one, and I've definitely had integrals with functions in the bounds, but never used them both at the same time ( or that I realized ).

So where is this typically found ?.
(Suppose I'm a Calculus 2 student and want to know when the next time I'd see this is)

physics and differential equations. they will be everywhere

I'm in a differential equations class and haven't seen it yet. The closest we've gotten is the Integrating Factor Method but that's just mostly taking the integral of a derivative. I haven't yet seen having function bounds for an integral and then taking its derivative.  Any idea when they'll start popping up (and what the reason will be)? Also, where in Physics? Is this typically found in a first-year Physics course? Or something like Electricity and Magnetism? (would love to know so I can look up the applications)

I would like to add though that I do recall a textbook question mentioning that we can express the solution to an ODE via integrals with function bounds (such as if solving the ODE required integrating something like e^(x^2)). Would a case then be that if we wanted to solve for missing constants via initial values, we'd have to take the derivative at some point? (but even then, if we can't evaluate the integral piece in the solution then how on earth would we be able to fully evaluate any initial conditions to solve for the missing constants?)

maybe like the time derivative of electric flux in faraday's law

Amazing! I will read about it.

Applications in electrodynamics: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/757090 and https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4838794

An example in electrostatics: https://reasonabledeviations.com/2017/07/25/leibniz-electrodynamics/

This is a special case of the Leibniz rule. In the general case, not only can the lower and upper bounds be functions of $x$, but the integrand can be a function of $x$ as well as $t$.

Here's a basic juicy example. Suppose $x$ is positive, and define
$$
L(x) = \int_{1}^{x} \frac{1}{t}\, dt.
$$
Differentiating the integral, we find $L'(x) = 1/x$ for all positive $x$.
Who cares? Well, since $L'$ is non-vanishing on an interval, $L$ is invertible. Further, if $a$ is positive, the function $f$ defined by
$$
f(x) = L(ax) = \int_{1}^{ax} \frac{1}{t}\, dt
$$
can be differentiated using one of our Arcane Rules, yielding
$$
f'(x) = \frac{a}{ax} = \frac{1}{x} = L'(x).
$$
By the identity theorem, $f$ differs from $L$ by a constant: $L(ax) = L(x) + C$ for all positive $x$. Since $L(1) = 0$, we have $L(a) = C$, or
$$
L(ax) = L(x) + L(a)\quad\text{for all positive $a$ and $x$,}
$$
which we recognize as a basic property of logarithms.
We saw earlier that $L$ is invertible. Let's denote the inverse function by $E$, so $E\bigl(L(x)\bigr) = x$ for all positive $x$ and $L\bigl(E(y)\bigr) = y$ for all $y$ in the image of $L$.
For general reasons, $E$ is itself differentiable. The chain rule (a.k.a. one of our Arcane Rules for differentiating an integral) applied to
$$
y = L\bigl(E(y)\bigr) = \int_{1}^{E(y)} \frac{1}{t}\, dt
$$
gives, for all $y$ in the image of $L$,
$$
1 = L'\bigl(E(y)\bigr) \cdot E'(y) = \frac{E'(y)}{E(y)},
$$
or $E'(y) = E(y)$. Since $E(0) = E\bigl(L(1)\bigr) = 1$, we've constructed a non-constant differentiable function equal to its own derivative. The identity theorem readily shows there is at most one such function. On the other hand, calculus students generally learn that the natural exponential function, $E(y) = e^{y}$, solves the initial-value problem $E' = E$ and $E(0) = 1$.
In words, we've given a short analytic definition of the exponential and natural logarithm in terms of definite integrals and their inverses, and used differentiating an integral to establish a couple of key properties. When I taught real analysis, this is how elementary functions were defined.

Here is a theorem that is often taught in the first days of a differential equation course:

For any first order differential equation of the form $y'=p(x)$ that is defined on an open interval, if the function $p(x)$ is continuous then any initial value problem for that equation has a unique solution.

Is that theorem familiar to you?
If you examine its proof, you will see the derivative of a definite integral in action.
For the existence part of the proof, suppose the initial condition is $y(a)=b$. Define
$$f(x) = \int_a^x p(x) \, dx + b
$$
and voila!
$$f'(x) = \frac{d}{dx} \int_a^x p(x) \, dx = p(x)
$$
$$f(a) = \int_a^a p(x) \, dx + b = 0 + b = b
$$
If you didn't have this theorem, I defy you to find a solution to that differential equation for the case that
$$p(x) = \log\left(\frac{\cos(x) + 7}{x^4 + (\arctan(x))^2 + 17}\right)
$$
(or any random continuous function for which it is impossible to find an antiderivative, other than by applying the first fundamental theorem of calculus.

Summary: The theorem which let's you take the derivative of a definite integral (affectionately known as the "first fundamental theorem of calculus) is a powerful tool for building new differentiable functions for many new applications. It is the tool underlying many theorems on existence of solutions for differential equations.
